# how to use spring tag library is there any jar needed

Tags: spring-mvc

When I added the tag library in JSP i got this exception.  I am using spring mvc with spring-security.

My JSP:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

     <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

    <c:set var="menuSel" value="MenuName" />
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url('resources/css/iCRL/iCRL.css');
    @import url('resources/css/iConfigure/iConfigure.css');
    @import url('resources/css/iConfigure/improvedDropdown.css');
    </style>
    <title>iCMT| iConfigure</title>
    <script>
    var context = "<c:url value=""/>";



    var include="<c:out value="getText('message.include')"/>;
    var exclude="<c:out value="getText('message.exclude')"/>;
    var itemToMove="<c:out value="getText('message.itemToMove')"/>";
    var confirmMsg="<c:out value="getText('message.confirmMsg')"/>";
    var fileReqrd="<c:out value="getText('message.fileRequired')"/>";   
    var textFile="<c:out value="getText('message.textFile')"/>";
    var compareDates="<c:out value="getText('message.compareDates')"/>";
    var validStartDate="<c:out value="getText('message.validStartDate')"/>";
    var validEndDate="<c:out value="getText('message.validEndDate')"/>";
    var selectFilter="<c:out value="getText('message.selectFilter')"/>";
    var FilterText="<c:out value="getText('message.FilterText')"/>";
    var differentCodeType="<c:out value="getText('message.differentCodeType')"/>";
    var validateAssoc="<c:out value="getText('message.validateAssoc')"/>";
    var NotToSearch="<c:out value="getText('message.NotToSearch')"/>";
    var NotToModify="<c:out value="getText('message.NotToModify')"/>";




     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="../admin/pgHeader.jsp" flush="true">
            <jsp:param name="menuSelected" value="iCRL" />
        </jsp:include>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/iConfigure/improvedDropDown.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/lib/jquery.Multiselect/js/jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>
        <div class="main_content_centered">
            <div class="main_content_outer_wrapper">
                <div class="s-content">
                    <div class="clean"></div>

                    <form action="iconfigure" method="post" name="configureForm"
                           value="iconfigure" id="configureForm" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="section_w1000">
                            <div class="module-info-container">
                                <div class="module-info">
                                    <div class="module-info-icon icfg-upload_icon"></div>
                                    <div class="module-info-content">
                                        <div class="module-info-title"><c:out value="Create Category"/></div>
```

After adding `%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>` I got this error

> type Exception report
>   message description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>   exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/iConfigure/pgiConfigure.jsp(90,26) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute value is mandatory for tag out
>
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:236)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:842)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2377)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1776)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:211)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:360)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
>         org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
>         org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
>         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
>         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>         org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>         org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
>         org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
>         org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
>         org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>         org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>         org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
>         org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>         org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Spring MVC.  The error message clearly states that a c:out tag is missing a value attribute at line 90.  I can't show you the precise code, because you only posted the first 60 or so lines of your JSP.